# Pandas: groupby under groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I'd be very grateful for your help as I cannot use the GroupBy on the group returned via pandas

How to use the group under the GroupBy as the df and df2 are both DataFrames...

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(
{"Product":{"0":"Product1","1":"Product1","2":"Product2","3":"Product1","4":"Product1"},"Part":{"0":"A1","1":"A1","2":"B1","3":"C1","4":"C1"},"Animal":{"0":"Cat","1":"Dog","2":"Cat","3":"Cat","4":"Dog"},"Value":{"0":702.0,"1":651.0,"2":640.0,"3":95.0,"4":556.0}})print(df)
print(type(df))
records=[]
for key, grp in df.groupby(['Product']):
    print(key)
    print(grp)
    print(type(grp))

    rec={}
    rec['Product']=key
    rec['Parts']=[]

    df2=grp[['Product','Part','Animal']]

    print(df2)
    print(type(df2))

    # grp3=pd.DataFrame(grp).reset.index()
    for key2, grp2 in df2.groupby(['Product','Part']):
        print(key2)
        print(grp2)

    records.append(rec)

print(records)
```

Comment: There's a typo in `for key2, grp2 in df2.groupby(['Product,Part'])`. Separate the column names.

Comment: Thank you a lot for help!
After the few days battle it was worth to ask...
@Chris: Thank you!